# Erro ao fazer uma requisição a uma API externa

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

estou tentando fazer uma requisição a uma API externa mas no console aparece o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código em Jquery:

```
 $("#Compilar").click(function () {
                var codigo = $("#CodigoText").val();
                var clientId ='a73f624a200e1e5d02845826ce3f5af7';
                var clientSecret = '698b340ea431e964a83deeafff295fb796a6e1ebde4978de3c48819c46c947d3';
                var script = codigo;    
                var stdin = 'StdIn';
                var language = 'c';
                var versionIndex = '3';
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    clientId,
                    clientSecret,
                    script,
                    stdin,
                    language,
                    versionIndex,
                    url: 'https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function (resposta) {
                        console.log(resposta)
                    },
                    error: function (resposta) {
                        alert(resposta);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Tudo bem entendi o que é, mas não resolveu meu problema...

Comment: Temos que ver algumas coisas.. esse erro ocorre porque a requisição para a API é de uma origem diferente, você tem acesso ao código fonte da API? se sim, você pode alterar para permitir requisições de qualquer origem, se você não tem acesso tem que ver na documentação da API o que é necessário para se comunicar com ela.

Comment: então o link da API é o seguinte https://www.jdoodle.com/compiler-api/docs, mas eu estou tentado fazer a requisição no pelo localhost o sistema não foi hospedado teira algo a haver?